# Is it possible to apply a set of styles to everything in a ViewGroup?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

From Android's documentation, a style resource only affects the specific view it is applied to, not child views under it.  In contrast, a theme (which is really just a style which is applied at the activity or application levels) affects everything within its domain.  So far so good.

What I'm wondering however is if I can apply a 'theme' but only for a specific part of my UI.  For instance, I am using a `LinearLayout` as a sort of ad-hoc Smart-Bar (think of it as a glorified status/toolbar) and as such, I'd like any (grand)child view that's added within it to use a specific value for the `tintColor` attribute.  (All child controls have a tint color defined via a getter/setter and an associated attribute.)

Currently, this requires manually adding the `tintColor` attributes to all the children manually as they are added. Things get more complex when there are grandchildren involved which may be part of an included layout, etc.

I'm hoping to simply 'theme' that base LinearLayout, but I'm not seeing any way to achieve this.  So can it be done?

Comment: As far as I know it cannot; a style is only for the item that you are assigned it to rather than the children. You can create individual styles for each of your elements and assign them, you can also store your tintColor in an xml so that it can be reused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `android:theme` attribute on your parent view.

Consider this example layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text 1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text 2"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text 3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This produces the following preview:

[image]

However, if I add `android:theme="@style/BlueText"` to my `LinearLayout`, I now see this:

[image]